# What firmware is my wireless card is using?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lubuntu

After a fresh install of Lubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Latitude D600, I'm having wireless issues. It has an Intel PRO/Wireless BG2200 and is using the ipw2200 driver.

I've read that I may need to update the firmware, but before I go installing something new I would like to determine what's already there. How do I find this out?

Comment: By the way, Lubuntu 12.04 has reached end of life (EOL) at the end of October, 2013 after reaching 18 months of support:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu#Support

Comment: The Lubuntu installer for 13.10 told me that the D600 does not support PAE and that I needed to install 12.04, so that's what I did. I think I'm stuck due to the age of the machine.

Comment: Have you tried Lubuntu 12.10, 13.04 or 13.10 with fake PAE?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE

In case of doubts:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151890

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out the current firmware, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

once the command runs look for the firmware version, under the Wireless interface.  See image below.

[image]